# New to Awk. Struggling with negative number formatting

Tags: awk

Goal: to output only data that is above 1 and below -1

or

output data that is between 1 and -1

I have the basics of awk and can print column 2 (where my data is)
notice I also specified a range of 0-1

```
awk '/[0-1]/  {print $2}' test.dat
```

I am also needing to have the line number so I added NR...

```
awk '/[0-1]/  {print $2 NR}' test.dat
```

To make sure I am clear, the point is to identify which lines of the data are outside of the acceptable range, so we can ignore them in our analysis. (ie anything bigger than 1 or lower than -1 is too much of a change).

Any help you can provide would be great. I have pasted some sample data below.

http://pastebin.com/7tpBAqua

Comment: I know shell scripting and awk (language) technically count as programming but I feel this question would get more attention if asked on unix.stackexchange.com instead of here.

Comment: @Wug True, but this isn't bash scripting, this is awk, a language.

Comment: I still think the Great Grey Neckbeards would know better.

Comment: This is my first post, I hope I was clear enough.

Comment: `awk '/[0-1]/'` does *not* match numbers between 0 and 1. It matches any line that contains a character between '0' and '1' inclusive - i.e. any line that contains either a '0' or a '1' character (at least in the most common locales). The fact that the vast majority of the sample numbers happen to have `|x| < 1` is coincidental.

Comment: Yeah, just noticed that my bad.

Comment: How do I match a range with a negative number?

Comment: @Wug I know how to answer this question; mainly, yeah, because I'm a Unix user and programmer. BUT I'm under 20, shaved, and I cut my hair monthly ;-)

Comment: Fledgling neckbeard.  Neckbeardlet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
awk -F'[ ,]' 'NR>2{for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) if ($i<-1 || $i>1) { print NR; next } }' file
```

Comment: Hey Ed, I ran that and it looks great! I'm going to manually check and verify. Thanks ;D

Comment: Almost there I think.... my output still counted the first two lines (which are not wanted, they are actually words and not data): 1 2 66 71 72 88 98 99 100 101 116 124 139 140 141 142 154 155 156 158 173 174 175 176 238 240 – user1783588 2 mins ago edit

Comment: @user1783588 Filter out the first two lines with `tail +3 file | awk -F'[ ,]' '{for (i=3;i<=NF;i++) if ($i<-1 || $i>1) { print NR; next } }'`

Comment: @user1783588 That is a stand-alone one-liner, replace `file` with your filename.

Comment: @TobiLehman: I updated my answer to skip the first 2 lines. No need for tail and pipe.

Comment: @user1783588: -F'[ ,]' sets the field separator to any " " or "," character so just count the values between spaces or commas in your sample input to see what it's doing.

Comment: @EdMorton That's a nicer solution.

Comment: #!/bin/csh -f

awk -F'[ ,]' 'NR>2{for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) if ($i<-1 || $i>1) { print NR; next } }' newdatatest.dat

Comment: FYI, you should not use [t]csh for scripting. See question 17 in the comp.unix.shell FAQ, http://cfajohnson.com/shell/cus-faq-2.html#Q17

Comment: I wanted to use bash but a co-worker really wanted c shell for some reason... not sure if I can escape this requirement....

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13131245/c-shell-awk-script-needs-revision-or-possibly-grep-solution-new-to-awk

Comment: In a nutshell, why not use c shell?

Comment: It was designed to be an interactive shell and is significantly different from all other shells which are designed for scripting. It is good at what it was designed for.

Answer (score 8):

Not sure if you want to evaluate the data in every column, or if there's a specific column you need to test. Testing a single column is simplest; testing multiple or all columns is a fairly simple repetitive extension of the pattern. Since you mention column 2 specifically, let's assume you want to print column 2 only when it is between -1 and 1:

```
awk -F, '($2 >= -1) && ($2 <= 1) { print $2 }'
```

To test for the field being greater than 1 or less than -1 instead:

```
awk -F, '($2 <= -1) || ($2 >= 1) { print $2 }'
```

Printing a different field, or the entire line instead (`$0`) should be fairly obvious. To examine each field, either simply repeat the entire `($2 >= -1) && ($2 <= 1) { print $2 }` clause for each field you're interested in (which quickly gets verbose), or something like this (not tested):

```
awk -F, '{ for (i = 1; i <= NF; ++i) if (($i >= -1) && ($i <= 1)) print $i; }'
```

Comment: I learned something from your answer, my attempt at an answer involved sed and egrep.

Comment: Thank you for your response twalberg. Could you assist me in printing only the line number? I know you can use NR to show the line number. So how would I conditionally print only line numbers that are say above 1 and below -1? In my data set there are 6 data fields, then a new line, when I posted it doesn't show like this....

Comment: Just replace `$2` with `NR`. Here is an example: `awk -F, '($2 >= -1) && ($2 <= 1) { print NR }' test.dat `

Comment: @user1783588 See Tobi's comment if you only need to print the line number if a single field is off. If you need to flag any line that has one (or more) fields that are off, something like this should work: `awk -F, '{ flag=0; for (i = 1; i <= NF; ++i) if (($i >= -1) && ($i <= 1)) flag=1; if (flag) print NR; }'`

Comment: For instance: the second to last line should be output but the last line should not. Thank you kindly for all your help. It has been years since I have coded so this is really a big help.

Comment: It works fine for me if I use the right test - note the one currently written tests for `>= -1` and `<= 1` (i.e. between -1 and 1). To find the inverse, you can use `if (($i <= -1) || ($i >= 1)) ...` in the appropriate spot...

Comment: Almost there I think.... my output still counted the first two lines (which are not wanted, they are actually words and not data): 1
2
66
71
72
88
98
99
100
101
116
124
139
140
141
142
154
155
156
158
173
174
175
176
238
240