# awk script needs revision or possibly grep solution (new to awk)

Tags: bash, awk, sh

I have a dataset like I have linked here: http://pastebin.com/7tpBAqua

Note the first two lines are not data(numbers), despite this, the 2nd line is associated with the 3rd line. Similarly, the 4th line is associated with the 5th line, and so on.

Currently, we have an awk script that outputs info on all line numbers that were above the threshold value (anything below -1 and above 1), this is the output:

```
71
72
88
98
99
.... and so on...
```

If the number is even we need to output the number that is odd after it (ie if 72, then output 72 new line then 73)

If the number is odd then we need to output the even before it (ie if 99 then output 98 new line then 99).

```
70
71
72
73
88
89
```

And so on…

Again, the idea is we are finding noise in this data-set and thus we need to eliminate it for the research to be valid. Thanks for any help you can provide.

Edit: from the solution provided below I have decided to break it down for my own personal learning as well as for anyone else who may read this:

```
"awk -F'[ ,]' 'NR>2{for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) if ($i<-1 || $i>1) print (NR%2==0) ? NR ORS NR + 1 : NR - 1 ORS NR; next }' file.txt
```

First we will craft a basic algorithm:

```
if (cur == even)
  print cur + \n + prev 
else if (cur == odd)
  print prev + \n + cur

-F'[ ,]'   # a flag for field seperator and designating it with [ ,]

'NR>2      # The total Number of input Records seen so far. 

{for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) # for loop starting at 2, ending when greater or equal to NR

if ($i<-1 || $i>1) # when these conditions are met then 

print (NR%2==0)    # print NR modulus 2

? 

NR ORS NR + 1      # current OR next

: NR - 1 ORS NR;   # comparisons?

next }'            # now go to the next NR

file.txt           # save to file.txt
```

Comment: please edit your question to down to 4-8 lines of sample data, with the required output. Also, as Stackoverflow is about helping programmers, and NOT about doing work for people, please include the code you have used so far, any error messages you're getting and your current output, marked up to indicate what is wrong. You can format the data and code so it is readable using the {} formatting tool at the top of the input box. Select all of your data and code and then click the {} icon. Good luck.

Comment: If it is a C shell script, it needs revising to use a real shell instead of a seashell.

Comment: What is an "awk c shell script"? awk and c-shell are two different scripting languages (the latter is primarily an interactive shell).

Comment: @Keith I used awk in a c shell script (ie my file extension was a .tsch)

Comment: And why haven't you shown us that script?

Comment: @shelter I was just starting to use SO at the time of this post and have since improved this question (by editing) as well as my overall approach, to add context to my original post (which is better now) at the time I was also working over full-time and going to college over full-time, so I was a bit rushed, further, the code was private due to it being university owned, so I could not publish it. Thank you for your concern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way using `GNU awk` and some of you're previous code:

```
awk -F'[ ,]' 'NR>2{for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) if ($i<-1 || $i>1) print (NR%2==0) ? NR ORS NR + 1 : NR - 1 ORS NR; next }' file.txt
```

Comment: If duplicate line numbers are a problem (they're probably not, but it's not clear in your question), simply pipe the command to `sort -nu`. HTH.

Comment: May I ask what the ORS is ? does that stand for or?

Comment: @user1783588: `ORS` is short for output record separator. By default it's a newline character. So instead of writing `ORS` I could have hard-coded it with `"\n"`. Did my solution work for you?

Answer (score 2):

Take the original code from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13126577/new-to-awk-struggling-with-negative-number-formating), and put in a conditional that tests the parity of NR. (Parity is the property of being either even or odd, it is tested by using the modulus operator: %).

```
awk -F'[ ,]' 'NR>2{for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) if ($i>=-1 || $i<=1) { if(NR%2 == 0) { print NR+1 } else { print NR-1} ; next } }'
```